# Correct missing fields values

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a class, that should support version tolerant serialization

```
[Serializable]
class A {
    [OptionalField]
    int a;

    [OptionalField]
    MyClass b;

    [OptionalField]
    MyClass c;
}
```

- How can I correct missing fields after deserialization? I guess, I have to use method marked with `[OnDeserializing]`. But how can I get which of fields was ignored?
- Can I configure auto-deserialization to initialize field by default constructor in case of them missing?

Comment: Why do you even use `[OptionalField]`? Can't you replace it with `[NonSeriablizable]`?

Comment: @Desolator cause I want to auto-serialize this fields. But NonSeriablizable is to ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally, you can use OnSerializingAttribute and OnSerializedAttribute to set the fields. As the example shows, fields that have been already set will keep their value. Note, however, that this is only the case if the field is set during the OnSerializing event. Fields set during the OnSerialized event will override the serialized value.

EDIT: In this case you can check in your method (decorated with OnSerialized) if the field equals to null and instantiate when necessary. If there is the possibility that this field is never be used and its creation can be deferred, think about hiding the field in question behind a property and instantiate it lazily.

Models.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SerializationExample
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Model
    {
        public Model(){
            A = new SomeClass();
        }

        [OptionalField]
        public int value;

        [OptionalField]
        public SomeClass A;

        [OptionalField]
        public AnotherClass B;            

        [OnDeserializing]
        void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            B = new AnotherClass("Set during deserializing");
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            // Do sth. here after the object has been deserialized
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("A: {0}\nB: {1}", A, B);
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public SomeClass()
        {
            Value = "Default";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public string Value { get; private set; }

        public AnotherClass(string v)
        {
            Value = v;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializationExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] FileNames = new string[] {
                @"model1.bin",
                @"model2.bin"
            };

            Stream[] files = new Stream[] {
                File.Create(FileNames[0]),
                File.Create(FileNames[1])
            };

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            Model m1 = new Model();
            m1.B = new AnotherClass("Set in app");
            m1.A.Value = "Set in app";

            Model m2 = new Model();

            Console.WriteLine("M1:\n{0}\n", m1);
            Console.WriteLine("M2:\n{0}\n\n", m2);

            bf.Serialize(files[0], m1);
            bf.Serialize(files[1], m2);

            foreach (var f in files)
                f.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            m1 = null;
            m2 = null;

            m1 = (Model)bf.Deserialize(files[0]);
            m2 = (Model)bf.Deserialize(files[1]);

            Console.WriteLine("M1:\n{0}\n", m1);
            Console.WriteLine("M2:\n{0}\n\n", m2);

            foreach (var f in files)
                f.Close();           
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
M1:
A: Set in app
B: Set in app

M2:
A: Default
B:


M1:
A: Set in app
B: Set in app

M2:
A: Default
B: Set during deserializing
```

Comment: Result of using [OnDeserializing] is fine, but I can't afford double initialization. It's to slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to initialize those values to defaults, all you need is a default parameterless constructor that initializes them. This will get called during deserialization, and any missing fields will keep whatever values you initialized them to in the constructor.

If you want more control, you can implement the `ISerializable` interface and the proper constructor on your class (you should usually do both, though often one or the other is unneeded.)

If C# finds a constructor with the signature:

```
protected A ( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
{
}
```

it will call that constructor, and pass a weakly-typed dictionary with all of the serialization information it has. (You can use `ISerializable::GetObjectData` to write custom fields into the object and retrieve them in the constructor). You can use the `info.GetXXX` methods to extract those values.

One thing to note: if you implement this constructor, you have to do *all* of the work, including the fields that would normally get deserialized automatically. For any missing fields, just set them appropriately. Similarly, if you implement `GetObjectData`, you have to serialize *everything* in that method. It's pretty simple, but if you change your class you need to edit your custom method/constructor appropriately.

Comment: > If you just want to initialize those values to defaults, all you need is a default parameterless constructor that initializes them.

I've chek it with binary serialization -- doesn't work. Possible you are talking about xml serialization?